# Cruise Control include.projects not recognized

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I have a very basic ccnet.config file, in which I am trying to use the include.projects tag to include a very basic project.  For some reason, when I use this tag the CCNet Server won't start, and I get the following error in windows EventLog:

> ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.ConfigurationException:  Unable
>   to instantiate CruiseControl projects from configuration document.
>   Configuration document is likely missing Xml nodes required for
>   properly populating CruiseControl configuration. **No loaded type is
>   marked up with a ReflectorType attribute that matches the Xml node
>   (include.projects)**.

Here is my ccnet.config:

```
<cruisecontrol>
    <include.projects file="MyTestProject.config" />
</cruisecontrol>
```

Any advice appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As detailed in the [documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuration+Preprocessor), correct syntax is:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
  <cb:include href="MyTestProject.config"/>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply skolima.  cp:include is one way to go about that - however it does have some drawbacks and not suit my current needs.  the include.project tag is also documented, and is what I am trying to get working.  See here for documentation: http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#include.projects

Comment: You are quoting the Java CruiseControl documentation, that's a different project. I believe the downvote was from you - would you mind removing it?

Comment: Oh the shame! You are correct. I was looking at Java documentation instead of .net :-#  I am still having trouble with the cb:include, but started a new thread about the (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698611/cruisecontrol-unused-node-detected-error-when-adding-xmlns-to-project-node). Thanks for following up.

Comment: As a brief aside to this, your included file will need the following wrapper tag around everything in it. <cb:config-template xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"> ... </cb:config-template>